# Can guest on VmWare detect USB device which host did not detect?

Tags: vmware, device-driver

I have a GPS device and its driver for Windows XP. I have Windows 7 on my laptop. I have no plans for any dual boot Windows XP and Windows 7.

I would like to know whether hardware support for Virtualization allows device to be detected in the scenario where no driver is available on host and there is driver installed on guest ?

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is "yes", but that doesn't mean that there won't be some issue with your specific case.

The virtualisation software virtualised access to the USB port, not the higher level, device specific protocol. I have used this to successfully use, for example, CAN networking hardware in a guest that was not supported by the host operating system.

The question probably belongs on Superuser, but I don't go there.